# How do we filter out radiation from galaxies from the cosmic background radiation?

Tags: cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, astronomy, big-bang, cosmic-microwave-background

[image]

When a whole sky view is done to get a picture of the [cosmic background radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_background_radiation) the radiation from our Galaxy is filtered out, and we are left with a picture which show radiation coming, more or less, from all directions. And the universal black-body-temperature is measured to less than 3 Kelvins. But the universe is filled with galaxies, as we can see from the [Hubble deep field](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble_Deep_Field) pictures. How do we filter all of these sources out? And if we can't filter them out, which error will it give? Can the error be large enough to question that we have a cosmic background radiation?

Comment: Possibly related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258571/

Answer (score 2):

The technique is to sight in on known frequencies of sources in the Milky Way and other galaxies. Any signal bearing the multiband set of data is subtracted.